# complex.h for other compilers than a win32 target, such as code composer studio (CCS)

Tags: c++

I have an error about including complex.h, I use CCS 5.2.1 for programming TMS320C6713  which is the embedded processor of a DAQ module that I have. The language is generally same as C++ with some compiler differences.

neither of these works out for me

```
#include <complex.h>
#include "complex.h"
```

I got errors such as "can not resolve ...." or "can not open the ... file"

what is the standard library that I should include, which calls this header indirectly, or how can I write this header file myself.

Comment: Can you quote *precisely* the error message you get please.  Preferably include a very short minimal program (`int main() {return 0;}` is just fine) below the two lines of code you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

"complex" is a C++ standard header (not inherited from C) as such it doesn't have a trailing ".h".  Try either of

```
#include <complex>
#include "complex"
```

Either should work.  For more details: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using an "old days broken compiler" like "turbo C++" or some MS compiler in compatibility mode, there is no `complex.h` header in C++.
the header is named `<complex>`

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/complex